# Jenkins connect with Git from Controlleer node but not with Agent node (Permission denied (publickey))

Tags: git, github, jenkins, connection, jenkins-job-dsl

Below is the error when we run the job from agent nodes in jenkins, it works fine when we run the same job on controller.

```
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress git@github.com:xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxx.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: ubuntu@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

1. Tried :  added ssh to git
2. slave node configured to git username and keys

Anyone have any clue , why the agent node is not connected with git

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

- a private key created without passphrase (that way, you don't need an SSH agent)
- said private key registered in the credentials, using the [Jenkins SSH Credentials Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh-credentials/#plugin-content-jenkins-ssh-credentials-plugin)

Make sure to select that credentials when using your SSH Git URL in the Jenkins pipeline definition.